# Read a complicated JSON with VB.NET

Tags: json, vb.net

I have a really strange json type here, has anybody an idea how I can read this playlists into vb.net? I tried it with Newtonsoft.Json, but I don't know, how I can get this deep to catch all items.

Maybe some one can give me an example, to get into this.

```
{
"kind":"sj#playlistList",
"data":{
    "items":[
        {
            "kind":"sj#playlist",
            "id":"f4976632-8b12-4eb1-9d9d-8789f86e145f",
            "creationTimestamp":"1386920817680369",
            "lastModifiedTimestamp":"1387214609186083",
            "recentTimestamp":"1387214609009000",
            "deleted":false,
            "name":"Jetzt wird gezockt",
            "type":"USER_GENERATED",
            "shareToken":"Token",
            "ownerName":"Owner",
            "ownerProfilePhotoUrl":"http://url",
            "accessControlled":false
        },
        {
            "kind":"sj#playlist",
            "id":"7f3189ff-ff50-485a-b4c8-f8c132ec6c6b",
            "creationTimestamp":"1386446415515553",
            "lastModifiedTimestamp":"1387228416316458",
            "recentTimestamp":"1387225951633000",
            "deleted":false,
            "name":"HipHop",
            "type":"USER_GENERATED",
            "shareToken":"Token",
            "ownerName":"Owner",
            "ownerProfilePhotoUrl":"http://url",
            "description":"",
            "accessControlled":false
        },
        {
            "kind":"sj#playlist",
            "id":"390138eb-6809-4c64-bd10-e41c804f205a",
            "creationTimestamp":"1387314202681616",
            "lastModifiedTimestamp":"1387836896131977",
            "recentTimestamp":"1387836895916000",
            "deleted":false,
            "name":"Playlist 2",
            "type":"USER_GENERATED",
            "shareToken":"Token",
            "ownerName":"Owner",
            "ownerProfilePhotoUrl":"http://url",
            "accessControlled":false
        },
        {
            "kind":"sj#playlist",
            "id":"c2223f04-863b-456c-ab8c-514751aaa584",
            "creationTimestamp":"1387744716502993",
            "lastModifiedTimestamp":"1387927152874338",
            "recentTimestamp":"1387927152657000",
            "deleted":false,
            "name":"Prinz Pi",
            "type":"USER_GENERATED",
            "shareToken":"Token",
            "ownerName":"Owner",
            "ownerProfilePhotoUrl":"http://url",
            "accessControlled":false
        },
        {
            "kind":"sj#playlist",
            "id":"935bfa54-36e4-452c-aa20-56c2835cb889",
            "creationTimestamp":"1387143940668642",
            "lastModifiedTimestamp":"1388067135056841",
            "recentTimestamp":"1388067134831000",
            "deleted":false,
            "name":"Playlist 1",
            "type":"USER_GENERATED",
            "shareToken":"Token",
            "ownerName":"Owner",
            "ownerProfilePhotoUrl":"http://url",
            "accessControlled":false
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Comment: .NET4.5 has [System.Json](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.json%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), I think you need to add it from Nuget though.

Comment: This isn't all that deep -- I would think NewtonSoft would be able to handle it easily.  Can you be more specific about the kind of problems you're having?

Comment: i dont know rly to use NewtonSoft, with php i have an easy JSON handle. i tried some things, but i only get the first "kind":"sj#playlistList" from the JSON. It would be very nice, if someone can create me an example for this.

Comment: A Google search turns up the home page for NewtonSoft's JSON.NET, which includes documentation and samples.  It's [here](http://james.newtonking.com/json).

Comment: yes i saw this, but there is no example that hits my JSON thing. i dont understand this JSON deserializing.

Comment: No one an idea how i can get this?